# POST an HTML form to a Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I just need a plain static .html page form, to POST to a Powershell script.

I've seen plenty of Powershell Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet material, but where Powershell is always initiating the HTTP request (and then handling the HTTP response..)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you hosting this .html file on a web server? If so, what is your webserver? Are you trying to handle to POST via javascript execution directly ( and addressing all the local access issues that come with it? )

Comment: Thank you, yes hosting the .html on a Web server - IIS.   

With prototyping in mind and little experience in .NET I was thinking that Powershell scripting could be a faster way, especially after seeing this Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. But reading your detailed answer below it becomes clear that it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot POST directly to a PowerShell script. When you POST to a website you are passing arguments to the web server that are then being presented to code on that web server ( the target of your POST request ) that the web server is capable of executing. Web servers do not understand PowerShell ( unless Microsoft has implemented this, which a few quick googles suggests they haven't ).

That being said, your ultimate goal is likely that you want to consume data that you sourced from a form via a PowerShell script. You will need to implement a backend on the webserver to consume the POST request and pass it to the operating system level to be run via PowerShell. This is generally not a good idea but if you are doing it for an internal site to get something running quickly then so be it.

Here is the process to call a Powershell script from ASP.Net: http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142

You could approach this problem in many other ways. You could write your backend site to save the data from the POST request to a file and come along and parse that file on a schedule with PowerShell. You could use a database in the same manor or you could create a trigger in the database to run the script each time a row is appended.

I suspect that if you work down one of these pathways you will ultimately find that the technology you are using on the backend ( like ASP.Net or PHP or JavaScript ) is capable of doing the work you need done and that you would have far less moving parts if you stuck with one of those. Don't be afraid to learn something new. Jumping to JavaScript from PowerShell is not that difficult.

---

And the world moves to fast. Here is a NodeJS-like implementation of a webserver in PowerShell.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Webserver-74dcf466